# How to include multiple variables in max() function?

Tags: c++

I have this simple but long code that outputs the electron arrangement when user inputs the atomic number of wanted element.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, s1, s2, p2, s3, p3, s4, d3, p4, s5, d4, p5, s6, f4, d5, p6, s7, f5, d6, p7;
    cout << "Atomic number: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    if(n<=2){
    s1 = n;
    }
    else if(n>=2){
    s1 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=4){
    s2 = n-2;
    }
    else if(n>=4){
    s2 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=10){
    p2 = n-4;
    }
    else if(n>=10){
    p2 = 6;
    }
    
    if(n<=12){
    s3 = n-10;
    }
    else if(n>=12){
    s3 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=18){
    p3 = n-12;
    }
    else if(n>=18){
    p3 = 6;
    }
    
    if(n<=20){
    s4 = n-18;
    }
    else if(n>=20){
    s4 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=30){
    d3 = n-20;
    }
    else if(n>=30){
    d3 = 10;
    }
    
    if(n<=36){
    p4 = n-30;
    }
    else if(n>=36){
    p4 = 6;
    }
    
    if(n<=38){
    s5 = n-36;
    }
    else if(n>=38){
    s5 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=48){
    d4 = n-38;
    }
    else if(n>=48){
    d4 = 10;
    }
    
    if(n<=54){
    p5 = n-48;
    }
    else if(n>=54){
    p5 = 6;
    }
    
    if(n<=56){
    s6 = n-54;
    }
    else if(n>=56){
    s6 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=70){
    f4 = n-56;
    }
    else if(n>=70){
    f4 = 14;
    }
    
    if(n<=80){
    d5 = n-70;
    }
    else if(n>=80){
    d5 = 10;
    }
    
    if(n<=86){
    p6 = n-80;
    }
    else if(n>=86){
    p6 = 6;
    }
    
    if(n<=88){
    s7 = n-86;
    }
    else if(n>=88){
    s7 = 2;
    }
    
    if(n<=102){
    f5 = n-88;
    }
    else if(n>=102){
    f5 = 14;
    }
    
    if(n<=112){
    d6 = n-102;
    }
    else if(n>=112){
    d6 = 10;
    }
    
    if(n<=118){
    p7 = n-112;
    }
    else if(n>=118){
    p7 = 6;
    }


    if(d3==4 && s4==2){
    d3++;
    s4--;
    }
    
    if(d3==9 && s4==2){
    d3++;
    s4--;
    }
    
    if(d4==9 && s5==2){
    d4++;
    s5--;
    }
    
    if(d4==4 && s5==2){
    d4++;
    s5--;
    }
    
    cout << "s1: " << s1;
    cout << "\ns2: " << s2; 
    cout << "\np2: " << p2;
    cout << "\ns3: " << s3;
    cout << "\np3: " << p3;
    cout << "\ns4: " << s4;
    cout << "\nd3: " << d3;
    cout << "\np4: " << p4;
    cout << "\ns5: " << s5;
    cout << "\nd4: " << d4;
    cout << "\np5: " << p5;
    cout << "\ns6: " << s6;
    cout << "\nF4: " << f4;
    cout << "\nd5: " << d5;
    cout << "\np6: " << p6;
    cout << "\ns7: " << s7;
    cout << "\nf5: " << f5;
    cout << "\nd6: " << d6;
    cout << "\np7: " << p7;
    
    return 0;
}
```

My problem with it is, when I input 57 for example, some variables are negative because code subtracts a certain number from inputted value. So I need to make those variables  0 if they are smaller than 0. I have 2 ways to do this and first is to write 19 new else if statements which is not efficient. My other idea is to use max() function but I don't know how to use it to include all 19 values and turn them to 0 at once. What do you all think I should do and how can I include multiple variables in max()?

Comment: With just a quick glance, it looks like much of your code could be replaced by a vector and one or more loops.

Comment: I don't really understand how. The electron arrangement levels are not regular, one time it increases by 2 next time it increases by 10, then 6, then 2 then 6 etc. How to do that?

Comment: Anytime you find  yourself naming variables v1, v2 ... you probably want to use a vector or an array instead of individual variables.

Comment: @AbdullahMertÖzdemir: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e880a90d7b33f5a) using array.

Comment: You have twice `if(d4==4 && s5==2)`. probably a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `std::max` with an initializer list:

```
auto max_value = std::max({x, y, z});
```

Note that the elements will be *copied* into the initializer list and the function will return a copy of the element with the largest value. This can become important if you use large objects (that are expensive to copy) and if time is of the essence. You could then instead just call it multiple times. This has the added benefit that it'll return a reference to the element with the largest value:

```
auto& max_element = std::max(std::max(x, y), z);
```

If you have many values, you may want to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and a standard algorithm, like [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). That algorithm will return an iterator pointing at the element with the largest value that when dereferenced will give you a reference to that element:

```
std::vector<int> values { ... };
auto& max_element = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't know about vector and algorithms yet, but I will look into them

Comment: @AbdullahMertÖzdemir You're welcome! Yeah, do that. They will simplify everything a lot! Even plain arrays would probably help to reduce  a lot of the duplicated code.

Comment: "elements will be *coplied*" - so what? Passing integers by copy is faster than by reference due to optimization. In the end `std::max(x, y)` will still make copies for pointers which are practically the same size.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M633b7eGd - there is **no** difference between versions with integer literals after optimization. I doubt there will be much of a difference in other cases. That means you point about copying is invalid here.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik `int`s are by definition very cheap to copy so I was perhaps a bit careless making that statement when `int` is the type use in the question. I'll work on rewording it later when I'm at my computer.

Comment: I would also mention the difference in return types. `std::max` with initializer list returns by value

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik True. I chose the receiving variable names to reflect that but it is too important to not also mention it.